# Select ng-model from object and ng-options from other object

Tags: angularjs

I am having a problem with my EDIT function in `<select>`.

**My sample code**

```
<div ng-show="!vm.loading" class="row" ng-repeat="data in vm.transaction track by $index">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
        <label>Item Name {{ data.item_name }}</label>
        <select ng-model="data.item_name" ng-options="item as item.item_name for item in vm.items""
            class="form-control">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**vm.items** is object for the `<select>` `ng-options`.

**vm.transaction** is the specific data response for EDITING.

In my other `<input type="text">` it is rendering a value.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Quantity</label>
    <input type="number" string-to-number class="form-control" ng-model="data.quantity" placeholder="123">
</div>
```

Plunker: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/J2z8VO3FValhdAa7sqbW?p=preview)

Comment: Unable to understand your question. Whats the problem you are facing and what's the error ?

Comment: sorry. the `<select ng-model>` doesn't render value from the object `<vm.transaction>`

Comment: is vm.items inside angular $scope ? or it's a plain js obj . if it is then you can use $root/$parent accr'dly.

Comment: Add jsfiddle or plunker? Without controller cannot fix the issue.

Comment: Show us how are you handling it i controller. Cant help with just html code. what data is expected in `vm.transaction` ?  create a plunkr to get quick resolution.

Comment: I created a plunker. Thank you. Here is the link: http://plnkr.co/edit/J2z8VO3FValhdAa7sqbW?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

To render the value, write ng-options as follows `ng-options="item.item_name  as item.item_name for item in vm.items"` following expression as **select as label for value in array**

```
<select ng-model="data.item_name" ng-options="item.item_name  as item.item_name for item in vm.items"
    class="form-control">
</select>
```